# jquery 1.9.0 live function?

Tags: jquery

There is no `live()` function in **jquery 1.9.0**, but **jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js** is already use this function.

Should I use older version of jquery or another way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depreciated as of 1.7 and removed as of 1.9. Use `on()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Lots of good info here:

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

As for Unobtrusive Ajax, you will need to include a version of jQuery prior to v1.9 where `live()` still exists.

If you are referencing the MS CDN,

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

then it does not appear that these directly reference jQuery. Simply include the 1.8 version in your code instead of the 1.9 version.

Comment: so, should I change all jquery.unobstrusive.ajax.js content?

Comment: jQuery.on() is a lot more efficient than .live(). if possible look for an updated version of the jQuery.unobtrusive library or find a replacement.

Comment: `.on()` isn't a drop-in replacement for `.live()`. What you have now is equivalent to `.click()`.

Comment: @thaJeztah I m using latest version of jQuery.unobtrusive, But get error `Object [object Object] has no method 'live'`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi normally I'd suggest to contact the author of the library, but after a quick Google, I realise this I part of Microsofts framework? I'm a bit surprised that they are so slow to adopt newer versions of jQuery (.live() was *marked* to be deprecated for some time now). However, there's a good chance that many people will run into the same problem and somebody has already created a patched version of Ajax.onontrusive that you can use until Microsoft releases a new version

Comment: @Blender, and your suggestions are not the answer that my excepted. I have already know them. Also your refrences of unobtrusive-ajax.js link already use live(). thanks...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, they aren't referencing any version of jQuery. The latest code on their CDN lists 1.4.4 as a minimum version.

Comment: this is the latest version. And it uses `live()` http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive

Comment: That version was posted Aug 2012. Long before 1.9 core shipped. What isn't clear is whether Nuget has a mechanism of restricting dependancies based on max versions. In this case, Nuget is likely just including the latest version of jQuery core. Try referencing 1.8 instead. Sure, Microsoft should fix this at the source level but the easy fix it just to reference an older version of jQuery.

Comment: Apparently it is open source and someone has already submitted a patch. https://twitter.com/bradwilson/status/296400359474212864

Answer (score 8):

`.live()` has been replaced with the event delegation syntax of `.on()`:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.child', function() {
  ...
});
```

`#parent` should exist when you call your selector, so if your element is top-level, use `document` as the parent.

Answer (score 2):

jquery.migate adds back in the legacy function. This means that jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js functions as expected.

Reference the jquery.migrate library as per the official blog and there is a nuget pacakge too but obviously you'll need to update your template/layout views.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Migrate/

Javascript console does highlight the issue ...

JQMIGRATE: Logging is active 
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated 
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack() 
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.clean() is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`live()` has been deprecated in the latest jQuery versions but Microsoft mantains updated unobtrusive scripts as NuGet packages that overwrite the default ones:

- [Microsoft.JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)
- [Microsoft.JQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/)