# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am clicking on button the following error is shown **"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'"**
    **My View page is as follows:**

```
@model Charis.Models.Products
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="../../Content/CharisSite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Prod", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table><tr><td>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <fieldset>
             <legend>Products</legend>

     <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Productname)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
             <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Productname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Productname)
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDiscount)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDiscount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDiscount)
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LanguageType)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
             <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LanguageType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LanguageType)
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
             <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
                </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
             <div class="editor-label">

               <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
               </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

     </table> 

    </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td></td></tr>
    </table>

    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>



    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Details</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumDescription1)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumDescription1)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumDescription1)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumDescription2)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumDescription2)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumDescription2)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cast)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cast)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cast)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectedBy)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DirectedBy)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectedBy)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProducedBy)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProducedBy)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProducedBy)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                           <label for="file">Upload Image1:</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                           <label for="file">Upload Image2:</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                           <label for="file">Upload Image3:</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                           <label for="file">Upload Image4:</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="file4" id="file4"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                           <label for="file">Upload Image5:</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <input type="file" name="file5" id="file5"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NoOfDisk)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOfDisk)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoOfDisk)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Format)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Format)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Format)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>



    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        <table><tr><td><fieldset><table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClear" />
                </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table></fieldset></td></tr></table>

    </td></tr>

    </table>

}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
*@
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

@if (TempData["notice"] != null) 
{
<p style="color:Red;" >@TempData["notice"]</p>
}
```

Comment: `live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9. Is that the version you're using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593724/jquery-1-9-0-live-function

Comment: [Live has been removed as of 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you are using jquery latest (1.9...) in which `$(sel).live(...)` was deprecated hence your error message.

1) revert to an older version of jquery.

2) update your code (replace live by on).

3) put back jquery-latest.

Answer (score 6):

You can also look into including jQuery Migrate to help with upgrading to jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across this after updating to jQuery 1.9 myself. However, I notice that none of the users (except AliRıza Adıyahşi in a link with no explanation) previously pointed out what part of your code was causing the error. After all, if 
`$(sel).live(...)` was deprecated in favor of `$(sel).on(...)` then it's a pretty simple fix, right?

The problem is that this error is being thrown inside `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, which you include as part of the bundle in `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Since you aren't using the Ajax form or cancel, the error is unlikely to affect anything (it doesn't on mine) but I was unable to find anything from Microsoft on a fix. The fix, unfortunately, is to go in and fix your version of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js replacing the .live calls to .on() until MS fixes the official one.