# client-side validation trips on DataAnnotation Range attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following code in my Model class:

```
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

After recent upgrade (I assume) of jquery.validate to 1.11.0, I am getting an error even if I enter valid value. If I turn off client validation in web.config - works fine. All other attributes (StringLength, Required) work fine. Generated HTML is the following (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." 
data-val-range="The field Price must be between 1 and 100." 
data-val-range-max="100" data-val-range-min="1" 
data-val-required="The Price field is required." id="Price" name="Price" 
type="text" value="" />
```

I am pretty sure it worked before... Can't think of anything but the bug in jquery.validate.

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: problem is about jquery not validate check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593724/jquery-1-9-0-live-function)

Comment: looks like it is a different problem; not related to jquery itself. Somewhere between jquery-validate and unobtrusive validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft issued an update to microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax and to microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation (from version '2.0.20710.0' to '2.0.30116.0') that fixes **both** .live and validation problems

Comment: I still have the problem with `2.0.30116.0`. I updated everything.

Comment: @Rowan, you probably want to start a new thread and put more details... I'll be happy to help; but I don't have the problem any more with 2.0.30116 - so it's hard to troubleshoot further!

Answer (score 12):

We are having the same problem with jQuery.validate 1.11.0 and Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 2.0.30116.0.  Somewhere in the validation library updates, the number validator broke.

There is an open issue on the GitHub issue tracker relating to this problem: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/626

Quoted in that issue:

> return this.optional(element) || ( value >= param[0] && value <= param[1] );
>
> Because this line checks strings, not numbers. If I have a range between 30 and 200, and I want to validate 120, then the string 120 is lesser then string 30.
>
> This line must be something like this:
>
> return this.optional(element) || ( Number(value) >= Number(param[0]) && Number(value) <= Number(param[1]) );

I have changed my copy of jquery.validate.js:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range
range: function( value, element, param ) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value >= param[0] && value <= param[1]) || (Number(value) >= Number(param[0]) && Number(value) <= Number(param[1]));
},
```

Now the range operations work as intended using DataAnnotations:

```
[Range(1, 100)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Looks like the actual adapter from Microsoft has the problem.  The adapter must be adjusted to parse a Number (look for adapters.addMinMax in code) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776965/please-support-jquery-v1-9-0-properly-in-jquery-validate-unobtrusive

Comment: +1 This workaround worked perfectly. Without it I was still having troubles as of 10 April 2013, even with the newest jQuery files.

Comment: The GitHub issue tracker in the link above reports the problem fixed in jQuery Validation V1.11.1 (published 25/03/2013). It now works for me. (I have Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 2.0.30506.0)

Answer (score 0):

This happening because you have updated Jquery version and new version of Jquery has different new updates and they have also removed some function like .live and replaced it with .on

Go through it...

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I also had a popup about .live no longer supported after I upgraded jquery to 1.9.1. Once I added jquery.migrate, the popup went away. *However* validation error still remains! It may have the same root cause; but adding migrate doesn't help; and I didn't find anything in the list - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md

Answer (score 0):

I run into this recently. I upgraded from MVC 2 to MVC 5. It seems that parameter name was changed from "minimum" and "maximum" to "min" and "max"

If you want to fix the issue without going through the hassle of upgrading your JavaScript files, search in your solution for these two lines and replace them with the better line

```
rule.ValidationParameters['minimum']
```

replace with

```
typeof(rule.ValidationParameters['minimum'])!='undefined'?rule.ValidationParameters['minimum']:rule.ValidationParameters['min']
```

and

```
rule.ValidationParameters['maximum'];
```

with

```
typeof(rule.ValidationParameters['maximum'])!='undefined'?rule.ValidationParameters['maximum']:rule.ValidationParameters['max']
```

Or alternatively, replace "RangeValidator" function with this code

```
Sys.Mvc.RangeValidator.create=function(rule){var $0=typeof(rule.ValidationParameters['minimum'])!='undefined'?rule.ValidationParameters['minimum']:rule.ValidationParameters['min'];var $1=typeof(rule.ValidationParameters['maximum'])!='undefined'?rule.ValidationParameters['maximum']:rule.ValidationParameters['max'];return Function.createDelegate(new Sys.Mvc.RangeValidator($0,$1),new Sys.Mvc.RangeValidator($0,$1).validate);}
```

Comment: Looks like you are extremely averse to the hassle of upgrading standard packages. Most developers are much more averse to *make changes* to standard packages, and in any event, upgraded from MVC 2 **years ago**!