# MVC5 Data Annotation issue - FireFox 30.0

Tags: firefox, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

Am having the model and added validation using Annotations. Validation was working fine till i updated to FireFox 30.0

Even my friend firefox browser renders the same code correctly.

```
  [Range(-10000, 200000)]
    [Integer] //From Annotaiton Extensions
    public int? someint { get; set; }
```

In my View if have

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.someint)  //validation works fine

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.someint)   // validation not working (eg: if i enter any char like "eer" , no validaition is fired)
```

Is it just me or any body else facing it ? Any workarounds ?

But everything works in IE8 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   [Range(-10000, 200000)]
   [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter numeric value..!")]
   public int? someint { get; set; }
```

Hopefully it works...!

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in the jQuery verison 1.9.1, if you are using this version of jQuery please update following:

> jQuery Validation (at least 1.11.1)

if you are using then following as well:

> Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation (at least 2.0.30116.0)
>
> Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax (at least 2.0.30116.0)

After this updation Range validation should work in Firefox or any other browser.

More detail can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889431/client-side-validation-trips-on-dataannotation-range-attribute/14989703#14989703)