# Data annotation validation for determining rage of data does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, data-annotations, database-migration

I want to restrict values of a column in database to range of data.

In this particular case, I want `Size` column restrict integer number between 1 to 4.

I've used `[Range(1, 4)]` for this goal.Size column has been created but can get any range of integer value!
Also about client validation I can enter any range of integer value!

How can I solve this problem?

I've used ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework 6.x, Sql Server 2008R2 and Code-First for creating database.

If it's necessary, your solution can be use by db-migration.

My model:

```
public class Tag : Entity, ITag
{
    [Range(1, 4)]
    public virtual int Size { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<ProjectTag> ProjectTags { get; set; }
}
```

a part of my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Size)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Size)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem apparently there is a issue with a version of jquery-validation so you can try using the following versions:

```
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation (at least 2.0.30116.0)
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax (at least 2.0.30116.0)
jQuery Validation 1.11.1
```

you can find similar questions here:
[client-side validation trips on DataAnnotation Range attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889431/client-side-validation-trips-on-dataannotation-range-attribute/14989703#14989703)

and another report about this here:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/626