# Why Validation message is always showing even if data is valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have defined something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.NumberOfThings, new {style = "width: 10%", @class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.NumberOfThings)
```

and

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value entered must be bigger than zero.")]
public int NumberOfThings{ get; set; }
```

But even if the data entered is in correct range, I am still seeing the error messgae label. Is there more things I should do?

Comment: What is the data annotation for NumberOfThings?

Comment: It is in the question. Do you need something else?

Comment: It should work. Chances are you may have to update the versions of jquery validation and jquery validation unobtrusive. There's a question with a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889431/client-side-validation-trips-on-dataannotation-range-attribute/14989703#14989703

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the type of the range?

```
[Range(typeof(int), 1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value entered must be bigger than zero.")]
```

It may also be to do with using int.MaxValue - you may need to write a CustomRange to handle using this as the values entered must be constants.

Comment: Surely int.MaxValue will not be an issue here since it is clearly a constant. Regarding using typeof(int) to make your value 1 explicity an int, could you explain why this would need to be done in this particular context? I would very much hope here that .Net would be clever enough to cast to constant implicitly, but it would be interesting to know if it's not able to infer this.